# Pronunciation: the verb "use" versus the noun "use"

Tags: pronunciation, homophones

Compare pronunciations:

- "I want to **use** the bathroom" (yoos)
- "I made **use** of the bathroom." (yus)

My poor attempt at creating a phonetically descriptive syntax is supposed to convey that, with the verb construction, "use" is pronounced with a long *u* whose sound continues during the speaking of the *s*. The noun construction is a shorter sound, where the *u* and the *s* are distinct.

It suddenly strikes me that this is such a slight change as to be barely noticeable if the listener is not already expecting it, or if the listener is not the speaker himself. So now I'm not sure whether I'm the only person doing this, and it's freaking me out a bit because I hate when I find out I've been mispronouncing terms for years; I'm too picky with my language for that.

So, is it just me forming a different pronunciation for "use" dependant on the context? Is it perhaps a regional thing? Or is everyone, indeed, doing it?

Comment: Worth noting that there are a few of these distinctions in pronunciation between a noun and a verb that are made by emphasis and length of vowel: contract n (/ˈkɒntrakt/) contract v. (/kənˈtrakt/),  - others at https://www.businessenglishresources.com/learn-english-for-business/teachers-section/mini-lessons/pronunciation-lessons-pronunciation-changes-in-words-that-are-both-nouns-and-verbs/

Comment: There are a bunch of doublets in English words that work by voicing or devoicing final fricatives: _life/live, smooth/smoothe, leaf/leaves, house (n)/house (v)_ etc.

Comment: You've selected the wrong answer here, Lightness!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about regional or dialect changes, but "use" has only one pronunciation for what concerns the "vowel" sound in it.

The last consonant sound changes, being [s] and [z].

It's **[juːs]** when it's a [noun](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/use_2) and **[juːz]** when it's a [verb](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/use_1), becoming **[ju:st]** when we have the construction "*used t*-o".

Answer (score 18):

The real difference between these pronunciations is that use (the noun) is pronounced with an /s/ and use (the verb) is pronounced with an /z/ (except in the construction *used to*). In English, vowels that are followed by a voiced consonant are longer than those followed by an unvoiced consonant ([see this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length#Allophonic_vowel_length)), and this is the source of the length difference you are noticing.

Comment: @PeterShor In fact, pre-fortis clipping seems to apply generally across languages.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you.
The use (yoos) of marijuana.
It depends on how you wanna use (yooz) it.
Not only does the length of the *u* change but the *s* sound changes to a *z* sound

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/414873)